# How do you share components across routes using React Router

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I am new to react/redux and trying to build a react application with an audio player that is "sticky" in the footer across pages. Meaning, if someone starts playing a track, that track continues to play as the user navigates other pages in the application. Think spotify or soundcloud.

My current code is structured in such a way that the audio player is in its own component, but I am wondering how I share that component across pages in the application.

I am currently including the player in the **FooterPlayer** component of each "page" like this

```
render(){

        const { width } = this.state;
        const isMobile = width <= 768;

        return(
            <div>
                <div>
                    <Header/>
                    {this.renderSeries(isMobile)}
                </div>
                <FooterPlayer/>
            </div>
        );


    }
```

The problem though is that when a user clicks a link to leave this page and navigate to another page, the FooterPlayer component will unmount. How do you structure applications with react router that allow you persist components and share them across "pages"?

Note, I'm also using redux if that is of help.

**Screenshot of an application page with the player in the "sticky" footer.**

[image: App Page with Player]

Comment: Either save the state locally and load the state on mount or put it into root component

Comment: How do you have a root component that persists across routes?

Comment: The component which you pass to the top level `render` call

Comment: @Dummy that did resolve it!